# Compiler doesn't see new method name - build issue but run time error. "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method"

Tags: android, methods, runtime-error, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I created a new Activity class from an existing class by creating it in the usual way and then cut and pasted code from my ScanActivity.class because the  new class was going to be very similar.

The new class is SenderActivity2.class. I also changed the XML onClick handler to have an onPicButtonClicked listener instead of the onScanButtonClicked of the ScanActivity class.

The gradle build works, as does the project build, but it fails at run time on the button click.

You can see in the logcat that it is still looking for onScanButtonClicked method.  I actually went in and changed the method name back to onScanButtonClicked even that method is in the other class to see if it would somehow work.  It did.  Also, there was an issue with the name created for the XML when I first created the new class and the XML was autogenerated. I think that may be a big clue as to the source of the problem.  I deleted the .gradle file in my home directory and forced it to rebuild everything, but that didn't help.  Hoping some of you have come across something similar.  I know there is a file somewhere that needs to be rebuild..just don't know what or where it is.

```css
01-29 22:19:57.714  12606-12606/com.blissbot.hallmarktest I/SELinux﹕ Function: selinux_android_load_priority [0], There is no sepolicy file.
01-29 22:19:57.714  12606-12606/com.blissbot.hallmarktest I/SELinux﹕ Function: selinux_android_load_priority , loading version is VE=SEPF_SPH-L720T_4.4.2_0032
01-29 22:19:57.714  12606-12606/com.blissbot.hallmarktest I/SELinux﹕ selinux_android_seapp_context_reload: seapp_contexts file is loaded from /data/security/spota/seapp_contexts
01-29 22:19:57.714  12606-12606/com.blissbot.hallmarktest D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
01-29 22:19:57.844  12606-12606/com.blissbot.hallmarktest W/ApplicationPackageManager﹕ getCSCPackageItemText()
01-29 22:19:57.904  12606-12606/com.blissbot.hallmarktest E/MoreInfoHPW_ViewGroup﹕ Parent view is not a TextView
01-29 22:19:58.014  12606-12606/com.blissbot.hallmarktest I/Adreno-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:381>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  (CL3869936)
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: 17.01.11.SPL
    Build Date: 01/17/14 Fri
    Local Branch:
    Remote Branch:
    Local Patches:
    Reconstruct Branch:
01-29 22:19:58.064  12606-12606/com.blissbot.hallmarktest D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
01-29 22:20:00.066  12606-12606/com.blissbot.hallmarktest W/ApplicationPackageManager﹕ getCSCPackageItemText()
01-29 22:20:00.086  12606-12606/com.blissbot.hallmarktest E/MoreInfoHPW_ViewGroup﹕ Parent view is not a TextView
01-29 22:20:00.106  12606-12606/com.blissbot.hallmarktest D/dalvikvm﹕ Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.blissbot.hallmarktest-114/libjmoodstocks-sdk.so 0x429498b8
01-29 22:20:00.106  12606-12606/com.blissbot.hallmarktest D/dalvikvm﹕ Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.blissbot.hallmarktest-114/libjmoodstocks-sdk.so 0x429498b8
01-29 22:20:00.106  12606-12606/com.blissbot.hallmarktest D/dalvikvm﹕ No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/com.blissbot.hallmarktest-114/libjmoodstocks-sdk.so 0x429498b8, skipping init
01-29 22:20:00.106  12606-12606/com.blissbot.hallmarktest D/dalvikvm﹕ Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.blissbot.hallmarktest-114/libjmoodstocks-sdk-core-armv7-neon.so 0x429498b8
01-29 22:20:00.106  12606-12606/com.blissbot.hallmarktest D/dalvikvm﹕ Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.blissbot.hallmarktest-114/libjmoodstocks-sdk-core-armv7-neon.so 0x429498b8
01-29 22:20:00.106  12606-12606/com.blissbot.hallmarktest D/dalvikvm﹕ No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/com.blissbot.hallmarktest-114/libjmoodstocks-sdk-core-armv7-neon.so 0x429498b8, skipping init
01-29 22:20:00.166  12606-12606/com.blissbot.hallmarktest D/Moodstocks SDK﹕ Sync will start.
01-29 22:20:00.376  12606-12606/com.blissbot.hallmarktest D/Moodstocks SDK﹕ Sync succeeded (7 images)
01-29 22:20:06.342  12606-12606/com.blissbot.hallmarktest D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
01-29 22:20:06.342  12606-12606/com.blissbot.hallmarktest W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41708da0)
01-29 22:20:06.352  12606-12606/com.blissbot.hallmarktest E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.blissbot.hallmarktest, PID: 12606
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method onScanButtonClicked(View) in the activity class com.blissbot.hallmarktest.SenderActivity2 for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'button'
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3956)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4633)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19330)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: onScanButtonClicked [class android.view.View]
            at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:472)
            at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:857)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3949)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4633)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19330)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-29 22:20:08.074  13193-13193/com.blissbot.hallmarktest W/ApplicationPackageManager﹕ getCSCPackageItemText()
01-29 22:20:08.124  13193-13193/com.blissbot.hallmarktest E/MoreInfoHPW_ViewGroup﹕ Parent view is not a TextView
01-29 22:20:08.234  13193-13193/com.blissbot.hallmarktest I/Adreno-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:381>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  (CL3869936)
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: 17.01.11.SPL
    Build Date: 01/17/14 Fri
    Local Branch:
    Remote Branch:
    Local Patches:
    Reconstruct Branch:
01-29 22:20:08.284  13193-13193/com.blissbot.hallmarktest D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
```

SenderActivity2 Code..

```
public class SenderActivity2 extends Activity implements Scanner.SyncListener {

// Moodstocks API key/secret pair
private static final String API_KEY = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
private static final String API_SECRET = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

private boolean compatible = false;
private Scanner scanner;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_recipient);

    compatible = Scanner.isCompatible();
    if (compatible) {
        try {
            scanner = Scanner.get();
            String path = Scanner.pathFromFilesDir(this, "scanner.db");
            scanner.open(path, API_KEY, API_SECRET);
            scanner.setSyncListener(this);
            scanner.sync();
        } catch (MoodstocksError e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}// On Create END

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (compatible) {
        try {
            scanner.close();
            scanner.destroy();
            scanner = null;
        } catch (MoodstocksError e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


public void onPicButtonClicked(View view) {
    if (compatible) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, PicActivity.class));
    }
}

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".SenderActivity2"
android:background="@drawable/hallmark_2">

<TextView
    android:focusable="false"
    android:selectable="false"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tapcrownTextPic"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:text="@string/touch_crown"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_marginTop="107dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:id="@+id/buttonPic"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:background="@null"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tapcrownTextPic"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tapcrownTextPic"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tapcrownTextPic"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:onClick="onPicButtonClicked" />
```

NEW INFO

I noticed that the error refers to button.  you can see in the screenshot that i've renamed it, yet it still thinks its "button"
[image]
[image: Activity_Sender_2 Design and Text views showing "button" "buttonPic" and onClick handler]

[image: buttonPic Design View]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I forgot to change the layout in onCreate bundle after copying the guts from RecieverActivity to Sender activity so it was getting the layout info for the wrong Activity.  should have been setContentView(R.layout.activity_sender_2); not setContentView(R.layout.activity_recipient);

Answer (score 1):

Just add 
public void onScanButtonClicked(View)
{
}
method in your  SenderActivity2 class.

you have to add this method because you define onScanButtonClicked in your respective xml.

Comment: not sure why the downvote.. i have researched this well and explained it in detail

Comment: please see new screen shots.. this is not a simple matter of misnaming a method.. there are two similar sounding methods... one is onScanButtonClicked in RecipientActivity.java and the other is onPicButtonclicked in SenderActivity2.java.  Yet at runtime it is looking for onScanButtonClicked when clicking the buttonPic button  in Activity_Sender_2 XML..  below is a screenshot of the RecipientActivity.java since i've only shown the SenderActivity2.java so far.  There is something up with the button IDs because you can see in the error message

Comment: There is something up with the button IDs because you can see in the error message that it refers to "button" and not buttonPic as would expect when clicking that button.  "button" is the name of the button in RecipientActivity.java for the onScanButtonClicked event